# Converting New With from C# to VB.NET - Compilation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005, code-conversion

I have the following code in C#:

```
public static ArrayList GetGenders()
{
    return new ArrayList()
    {
        new { Value = 1, Display = "ap" },
        new { Value = 2, Display = "up" }
    };
}
```

It's working fine. However, when I converted it to VB.NET:

```vb
Public Shared Function GetGenders() As ArrayList
    Return New ArrayList() From { _
        New With { _
            .Value = 1, _
            .Display = "ap" _
        }, _
        New With { _
            .Value = 2, _
            .Display = "up" _
        } _
    }
End Function
```

I get the following compile-time error:

> BC30205: End of statement expected.

What's the problem with the code?

Comment: What error do you get? What version of VB?

Comment: Define "it's not working."  Do you get an error?  Compile-time or run-time?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Constructing a `List<T>` here is non-trivial.

Comment: My bad. Didn't notice the anonymous type.

Comment: i am using .net 2.0 framework

Comment: What version of Visual Studio/Visual Web Developer?

Answer (score 3):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you're using VB.Net 2005, which [does not support anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: s iam using vb.net 2005.so no solution?

Comment: You can create a named class, or you can use a later version.

Comment: Or use a `List(of ListItem)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That won't help replace the anonymous type.

Comment: @Slaks: Not all anonymous types, but maybe this specific case where he needs a type with a property `Value` and a property `Display`. Why should he create a new class when it's already existing?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that this is a version of VB.Net prior to 2010, in which case the `FROM` syntax isn't available (I had the same issue earlier with some code converted by developerfusion - I was going from C# in .Net 4 to VB.Net in .Net 3.5)

The following 2 stage process should do it - not found a way of making it a single line yet:

```
Dim arr() = { _
    New With {.Value = 1, .Display = "ap"}, _
    New With {.Value = 2, .Display = "up"} _
}
return = New ArrayList(arr)
```

Comment: Correction: According to comments this is in .Net 2, in which case the above anonymous types aren't available. However I'm leaving the answer up for reference for other users having problems with `FROM`

Answer (score 0):

A VB2005-specific answer involves creating a class to hold the values, then populating the arraylist with instances of the class.

The class:

```
Public Class LookupList
    Private m_Value As Integer
    Private m_sDisplay As String

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal wValue As Integer, ByVal sDisplay As String)
        Me.New()
        Me.Value = wValue
        Me.Display = sDisplay
    End Sub

    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_Value = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Display() As String
        Get
            Return m_sDisplay
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_sDisplay = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And the method:

```
Public Shared Function GetGenders() As ArrayList
    Dim oList As New ArrayList
    oList.AddRange(New LookupList() {New LookupList(1, "ap"), New LookupList(2, "up")})
    Return oList
End Function
```

A solution that is slightly more inline with the original C# code is to create a collection class for the class:

```
Public Class LookupListCollection
    Inherits System.Collections.Generic.List(Of LookupList)

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal ParamArray aItems As LookupList())
        Me.New()
        If aItems IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.AddRange(aItems)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

which can then be called as:

```
Public Shared Function GetGenders() As LookupListCollection
    Return New LookupListCollection(New LookupList(1, "ap"), New LookupList(2, "up"))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lista.Add(New InvValorMedio With {.Data_Base = _dataBase, _
                                  .Tipo = item.IdInvTipo, _
                                  .Valor = 0})
```

Comment: If this is an answer, please add some description